# How to verify if post is shared on facebook

Tags: facebook, share

I have an URL and it has many features. I want to disable one feature and enable it only if the app is shared on facebook. I have implemented share button, only problem is i will not know if the app is really shared on facebook or not. Users can click on share button and in the popup cancel it and the feature gets enabled as of now.

Kindly let me know if detection is possible via facebook javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Share Gating is not allowed, users MUST share/like/comment something only because they really want to, you are not allowed to reward them in any way or gate content behind those actions.

Afaik the only way to implement this is to authorize the user with `publish_actions`, in that case you will get the post id in the callback. But you will never get `publish_actions` approved for something that is not allowed, obviously.